# Типизация в Python. Какой лучший способ гарантировать что переменная будет ожидаемого типа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В Python пришёл из строго-типизированных языков и видимо не могу перестроиться.

Часто программы оказываются весьма хрупкими из-за того что не получатся найти оптимальный способ гарантировать что в переменной будет ожидаемый тип.

Собственно вопрос к гуру:

Если я ожидаю к примеру dict и соответственно выполняю my_dict['key'] = value то в некоторых случаях есть вероятность что my_dict окажется к примеру string и естественно я получу исключение.

При это конструкции:

```
my_dict: dict = 'some_string' #не вызовет исключения.
my_dict = {}; my_dict = 'some_string' #также не вызовет исключения
```

Неужели единственный способ это проверять тип всех переменных которые потенциально могут принять неожиданный тип ?

```
if type(my_dict) is dict:   my_dict['key'] = value
```

**Есть более рациональный подход ? Как вы решаете подобные проблемы ?**

Comment: Никак не гарантировать. Для полей объектов можно еще прикрутить какую-нибудь валидацию внешними фреймворками (типа pydantic), для одиночных переменных - никак.

Comment: Ну, надо бить по рукам тому, кто в переменной `my_dict` передаёт строку. А так то ну что вы хотите от языка без строгой типизации.

Comment: Ну, допустим, проверите вы в рантайме, что это не словарь, и как отреагирует ваша программа? В газету объявление напишет? Скорее всего, никак кроме падения она отреагировать не сможет, а падение будет и без ваших проверок. Другой вопрос, что статически типизированные языки проверяют это еще до рантайма, В python для этого используются утилиты вроде [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) (само собой, сильно ограниченные в возможностях)

Comment: Когда мы говорим о сколько ни будь не связанной архитектуре приложения, каждый элемент такого приложения может вернуть неожиданный тип, особенно если над приложением работает больше одного бедолаги-программиста. Реагировать на такое можно множеством способов от приведения к нужному типу до игнорирования. Вопрос как раз в том как (какие существуют практики), либо на этапе создания переменной гарантировать что тип не изменится в течении всего цикла жизни, либо на этапе вызова определить тип переменной. Кстати вариант с валидацией полей объектов, выглядит не плохо.

Comment: @MilkyWay я не говорю, что проблемы нет, я говорю, что решать ее в рантайме (как-то кроме падения с логированием) поздно, если конечно речь не о фильтрации внешних данных. Предложенная мной утилита забракует ваш пример кода

Comment: @extrn не совсем согласен, решение проблем в рантайме это одно из ключевых приемуществ не тепезированных языков. Что касается сторонних утилит, встраивать в самое сердце кода утилиту которая не факт что не содержит кретических багов считаю не рацианальным (предлагаемая утилита даже до версии 1 не добралась).  Суть вопроса скорее в наботе практик, патернов, если хотите, алгоритмов которые часто используют более опытные коллеги для решения описанной проблемы.

Comment: @MilkyWay обычный набор практик: использование статических анализаторов (встроенного в PyCharm, внешних mypy, flake8, или других), обкладывание кода аннотациями типа, с такой силой, как будто тебя покусал джавист, прикручивание валидаторов, там где статический анализатор не может спрогнозировать тип.

Comment: @MilkyWay Главное преимущество python - быстрая разработка, этому способствует очень простой синтаксис и динамическая типизация. Главный недостаток python - все проблемы приходится решать в рантайме, а не на этапе компиляции. Ровно по тем же причинам. Не записывайте недостатки в достоинства.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, чаще всего используют конструкцию `isinstance(variable, class)`. Т.к. даже базовые типы в python являются классами, вы всегда можете проверить переменную на принадлежность к тому или иному типу примерно следующим образом:

```
isinstance(bar, (float, int, str, list, dict, tuple)) # Проверит, что тип переменной является одним из типов, перечисленных здесь
isinstance(foo, int) # Проверит, что переменная целочиселнная и т.д.
```

Comment: симантически решени ни чем не отличается от проверки типа через if. Хотя безусловно изящьней если нужно проверить на пренадлежность к нескольким типам, но вопрос совсем о другом.